ValueError: mismatch in send count 2 and receive count 8
I've this MPI_example.py file to solve a matrix:
from mpi4py import MPI
import numpy as np
from scipy.stats import ortho_group
from scipy.sparse import spdiags


def generate_matrix(dim):
    a = ortho_group.rvs(dim, random_state=0)
    b = np.linspace(1., 10., dim)
    return a @ spdiags(b, 0, dim, dim) @ a.T


def power_iteration(A, b, num_iters):
    for _ in range(num_iters):
        b_new = A @ b
        b_new_norm = np.linalg.norm(b_new)
        b = b_new / b_new_norm
    return b


comm = MPI.COMM_WORLD
rank = comm.Get_rank()
size = comm.Get_size()


n = 8  
num_iters = 100


if rank == 0:
    A = generate_matrix(n)
else:
    A = None


rows_per_proc = n // size
local_A = np.zeros((rows_per_proc, n))
comm.Scatter(A, local_A, root=0)


if rank == 0:
    b = np.ones(n)
else:
    b = np.zeros(n)

comm.Bcast(b, root=0)


for _ in range(num_iters):
    local_b_new = local_A @ b
    global_b_new = np.zeros(n)
    comm.Allreduce(local_b_new, global_b_new)
    norm = np.linalg.norm(global_b_new)
    b = global_b_new / norm


if rank == 0:
    estimated_eigenvalue = np.dot(b.T, A @ b) / np.dot(b.T, b)
    print(f"Eigen vector estimated: {estimated_eigenvalue}")
    print(f"Error: {abs(10 - estimated_eigenvalue)}")

import time
start_time = time.time()

end_time = time.time()
if rank == 0:
    print(f"Time: {end_time - start_time} [s]")

Im running it in Google Colab, so Im trying this:
from google.colab import files
uploaded = files.upload() #select MPI_example.py
!ls #check .py file
!pip install mpi4py
import mpi4py
print(mpi4py.__version__)

And then I run all the code using:
!mpirun --allow-run-as-root --oversubscribe -n 4 python MPI_example.py

But Im getting this error:
ValueError: mismatch in send count 2 and receive count 8
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
Primary job  terminated normally, but 1 process returned
a non-zero exit code. Per user-direction, the job has been aborted.
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
mpirun detected that one or more processes exited with non-zero status, thus causing
the job to be terminated. The first process to do so was:

  Process name: [[21624,1],2]
  Exit code:    1

I want to try differents n in !mpirun --allow-run-as-root --oversubscribe -n 4 python MPI_example.py. How can I fix this error? and whats wrong ?

Your application only uses collective communication. For collective communication the size of sent data and received data always need to match. The error message says that one of your collectives sends only 2 elements and wants to receive 8 elements. If I understand the code right, local_b_new has only 2 elements. If global_b_new is supposed to be the concatenation of all local bs, the right collective is allgather instead of allreduce.

Replacing Allreduce by Allgather, I get a reproducible result independent of the number of parallel processes (after increasing n to support a higher number of MPI processes):
#    comm.Allreduce(local_b_new, global_b_new)
    comm.Allgather(local_b_new, global_b_new)

Allreduce performs the default op=SUM on all elements of the vector and distributes the result to all processes. local_b_new only contains the local partition of b, so element-wise sum is not the right operation. Gather collects all vectors, concatenates them and distributes the result to all processes.
